# Eclipse - Show @SuppressWarnings(value={"all"}) when lombok's Data and Constructor added

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok, suppress-warnings

I have a class with lombok's `@Data` and `@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)`:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class ResponseVO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3461582576096529916L;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "amount", isAttribute = true)
    String amount;
 }
```

When I'm using the constructor

```
new ResponseVO("22222");
```

I'm getting a warning inside tooltip when hovering over constructor method:

```
ResponseVO.ResponseVO(String amount)
@SuppressWarnings(value={"all"})
```

Why this warning added ? without `@Data` it disappears

[image]

Class decompile without any warnings:

```
public class ResponseVO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3461582576096529916L;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "amount", isAttribute = true)
    String amount;

    public String getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (!(o instanceof ResponseVO)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            ResponseVO other = (ResponseVO) o;
            if (!other.canEqual(this)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                String this$amount = this.getAmount();
                String other$amount = other.getAmount();
                if (this$amount == null) {
                    if (other$amount != null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (!this$amount.equals(other$amount)) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
        return other instanceof ResponseVO;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        boolean PRIME = true;
        byte result = 1;
        String $amount = this.getAmount();
        int result1 = result * 59 + ($amount == null ? 43 : $amount.hashCode());
        return result1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "ResponseVO(amount=" + this.getAmount() + ")";
    }

    public ResponseVO(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _warning_? The `@SuppressWarnings` annotation?

Comment: Obviously the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is added by Lombok when `@Data` is added to avoid warnings from popping up for the by Lombok generated code.

Comment: The whole constructor is added by Lombok, or do I get it completely wrong here?

Comment: You could decompile the `.class` file to see what error messages would appear for the generated code without `@SuppressWarnings(value={"all"})`.

Comment: @howlger I edit my question, no warnings/errors

Comment: I guess there would only be warnings in certain cases or/and with certain settings, but it is easier for Lombok to always add the annotation instead of add it only in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a warning, it is the regular Eclipse tooltip which appears on all classes, methods etc. Those tooltips show the JavaDoc of the respective element (which is empty in this case) and also list all annotations on the element.
And this is why you see the `@SuppressWarnings`: It is generated by Lombok to avoid that the compiler emits warnings on Lombok generated code.

The question remains why Lombok would generated those suppression annotations.
Typically, Lombok's code will not produce any warnings. However, new Java language or compiler versions may result in new types of warnings or new deprecations. Running a non-adapted Lombok version targeting a newer Java version therefore may produce warnings. As users will not be able to fix those warnings, those warnings are suppressed.
Furthermore, adding `@SuppressWarnings("all")` also suppresses non-standard warnings, e.g. from code linters or in code analysis integrated in IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: It happens only when added `@Data`, and not other lomobok annotation

Comment: No, I just checked (using Lombok 1.18.6 and Eclipse 2018-09) that only `@AllArgsConstructor` also shows it. If you take a look at Lombok's test suite, you see it everywhere: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/tree/master/test/transform/resource/after-ecj

Comment: `@AllArgsConstructor` without `@Data` doesn't produce me the warning